# How do you change the vertical position of an image?

Tags: graphics, positioning

[image: panel]

I'd like to move the Stackoverflow icon lower so that it's level with the rest of the icons. I've tried using `\vspace` but it doesn't seem to affect the images, only the content below it.

This is what I have:

```
\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{github-64px}
\hspace*{2mm}
\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{stackoverflow}
\hspace*{4mm}  
\includegraphics[scale=0.15]{linkedin}
\hspace*{4mm}
\includegraphics[scale=0.12]{Blogger}
```

Comment: I suggest to  modify the images with a graphics program to get equal width and height.

Comment: `\raisebox{-5mm}{\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{stackoverflow}}` might work, but indeed there seems to be whitespace at the bottom of the logo that you could remove with an image editor.

Comment: Or `\includegraphics[scale=0.2,trim={0 5mm 0 0 0},clip]{stackoverflow}` maybe.

Comment: @Marijn That seemed to do it. Changing `5mm` to `10mm` in the `trim` attribute made it perfect. Thanks.